# How to transition from underground schedule 40 PVC conduit to EMT inside building through concrete slab?

Tags: electrical, conduit, emt

I'm running feeder wires in 1-1/4" schedule 40 PVC underground to detached structure. I plan on using a 2" sleeve for the slab pour and a long 3' radius sweep elbow conduit fitting to bring wires  up from the trench into the building. I was thinking of using schedule 80 for the sweep, but everyone here still uses schedule 40 for above ground transition and no one is really stocking schedule 80. Feeders will run in conduit on the surface of the wall to a surface-mounted panel. I was planning to use 1-1/4" EMT for the inside run. What transition couplings are available for this? And should I make this transition just after the schedule 40 PVC emerges from the sleeve? Other suggests for a better way to do this?

Comment: I take it the EMT is because you're concerned about mechanical damage?

Comment: In my area, any electrical supply has schedule 80, and no big box or hardware stores have any, other than pre-formed small-radius sweeps. They don't stock straight sticks, or large radius sweeps, but the electrical supply houses do.

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel Yes. Tight space and moving in a big, heavy water pressure tank.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm placing my electrical order soon.  I will check with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious options are a "conduit body" or a junction box. That also provides pulling access, which is likely useful at that point. That's what I'd do.

If you *really* don't need a pulling access point there (less than 360 degrees bend end to end from where you do have access) you can use a PVC to male threaded transition, a threaded coupling female to female, and an EMT to male threaded fitting. I have my doubts about it, but technically it works.

Comment: You can simplify that to a PVC *female* adapter with an EMT connector threaded into it

Comment: @Ecnerwal I really didn't want a junction because wall is already crowed with panel, control box, pipes. I only have two 90 degree sweeps (into and out of trench) and an offset to the panel box. It's the EMT to male threaded fitting I can't find. Is that set screws or compression on the EMT side? Does it have a name?